# Domain name URL defaults to IP address

Tags: iis, domain-name, ip-address, url

quick question really.

I have a domain name - say www.example.com and this is assigned to PORT 80 on IIS, the default port. On port 80, I have a front end brochure site, and an MVC web application. These two were worked on by two separate people however now have been integrated into a single project.

And while I can access the front end through the domain name, as soon as I try to login to the web application, it defaults to the IP address for the URL. I can still access the login screen & other areas of the web app using the domain name, but only if I type it in myself.

Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the initial request is routed and returned fine by the domain name, this sounds like something inside your app itself that is redirecting the user to the IP. It is not likely that the dns or iis server config would be causing this, more likely the actual code of the site or perhaps special headers it is returning are redirecting the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Caleb. Had figured out that there was no host name set for the site settings in IIS.

Comment: Huh. In that case my answer was only partially right. The host name shouldn't matter if the web app links/references things relativly, but if your app requests the server host name and then uses that to build absolute links/redirects you could run into this. So it was the app redirecting you, but the app was talking upstream to IIS and not getting information because the config there was incomplete. Glad you got it fixed.